# Adding headers to a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

So I have a `PreferenceActivity` subclass in my Honeycomb app and there should be functionality for adding accounts for a certain service. I use `loadHeadersFromResource` to load preference headers from the xml, but I also want accounts to be added to the header list, just like in **GMail** app.
Is there any way to do it without writing my own `PreferenceActivity`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to honeycomb it works on Android 2.1 etc. as well.
Just use PreferenceCategory as your headers and add the preference to the category.

Something like this in the onCreate.

```
PreferenceScreen pf = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
pf.setPersistent(true);
setPreferenceScreen(pf);

PreferenceCategory account1 = new PreferenceCategory(this);
account1 .setTitle("Account 1");
pf.addPreference(account1 );


Preference p = ...;
account1.addPreference(p);
```

Comment: Oh, never mind. It's not a problem in fact. Just didn't notice an obvious solution.